# Apache NiFi Supports Moving Data from HDFS to RDBMS systems?

Tags: apache-nifi

Have anyone used Apache NiFi for moving data from HDFS to RDBMS systems, Similar to SQOOP Export ?

If yes, how was the performance ?

Answer (score 1):

Akhil,

Performance depends a lot on factors outside of NiFi, i.e. network, disk IO, query performance. 
If you are simply pulling the data and pushing it, you can easily reach speeds of 100MB/sec. NiFi itself is not consuming a lot of resources and when you find NiFi to be the bottleneck, look into clustering it.

Comment: Vijay, which processors you have used for moving data to RDBMS systems, do you have any sample which I can refer ?

Comment: Akhil, I use InvokeScriptedProcessor (Groovy) to generate the bulk sql insert command, this generates a flow file which is the input to the PutSQL processor.